# Google Drive API & Google Drive Client error

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I’m asking the community to help me understand the problem of downloading files via Google Drive Client, and their subsequent downloading through Google Drive API
We have: **PHP** and **google/apiclient: ^2.0**

How we download now:

- Adding files to Google Drive Client;
- Google Drive (through watch **webhook**) sends notification about changes in the folder (directory);
- Our server requests list of files through **files.list** API method and adds them to the Google Drive API downloading queue;
- Once per minute our server tries to download a file from  Google Drive (**with files.get alt='media'**) and does this until the file length is more than 0 bytes (because Google Drive Client initially creates zero size files);
- Once the file is downloaded by our server from Google Drive we use **files.delete**

**The problem is:**
In steps 3,4 and 5 Google Drive Client shows uploads errors (An unknown error occurred) and files appear in the list as under-loaded. The thing is that our server has successfully downloaded that files and they actually are on our side.

Also sometimes Google Drive Client creates a file in Google Drive, but it has zero-byte size, and after that it stops any attempts to download the file.

*Any help appreciated! Please, advice. Even the tips at the level: where to pay attention and look closer would be great. 
Thanks in advance!*

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code we cant help you fix an error without seeing the code.

Comment: If you're having trouble following the alt=media download method as mentioned in the [Download Files docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads), try to use the [webContentLink](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource) instead. It's as easy as opening a browser window and passing the webContentLink as argument.

Comment: @noogui Thanks for the help! But the problem persisted even when using webContentLink instead of files get alt = media

Comment: It would be nice to include the code implementation and the corresponding errors. And, are you using service account or user account?